# How can I use a DLL from Python

Tags: python, dllimport, ctypes

I am trying to load a DLL in Python, I want to use its eConnect() function using [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes)

What I know from the source code of the DLL:

- from the *.cpp source code: `bool eConnect( const char *host, UINT port, int clientId=0);`
- from the dependency walker tool: function ordinal is 6 and undecorated name is
  `?eConnect@EClientSocket@@UAE_NPBDIH@Z`

I tried to access the eConnect from two ways myfunction and myfunction2, but I probably get it wrong. Here is my code:

```
from ctypes import *

def main():

IP = c_char_p('127.0.0.1')
port = c_uint(7496)
client_id = c_int(0)

myfunction = getattr(cdll.TwsSocketClient, "?eConnect@EClientSocket@@UAE_NPBDIH@Z")
myfunction2= cdll.TwsSocketClient[6]

print myfunction
print myfunction2

print myfunction(IP, port, client_id,IP)

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

I get the below error:

"WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000002D"

I would badly need some help here (I do not know c++).
Thanks!

Comment: Is the function being exported from the C++ code as `stdcall` or `cdecl`? Also, I'd wrap it in an `extern "C"` so that you don't get that revolting mangled name!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers everyone. I took Adam's advise and reconsidered my approached. As I do not know know c++, it was a bad idea from the start.

There is an alternative API in R (not official) which is built on top of the official Java API. It is then quite easy to link R and Python using rPy2.

Answer (score 4):

To make things easier, more Pythonic, you might want to look into ctypesgen:

http://code.google.com/p/ctypesgen/

It will generate proper wrapper functions, data types and such for you.  If you just want to know how to use ctypes, might as well start with the tutorial:

http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html

Anything more specific and I'll have to read the API for the DLL you're attempting to use.

Comment: +1 ctypesgen? Never knew that existed, and I've done a good bit of ctypes. Thanks for the steer!!

Comment: Yeah, we use it to generate one of the Python bindings for Subversion.  It's really slick.

Answer (score 1):

The function being exported is a class member function of the class `EClientSocket`.  You're attempting to call that function from Python without passing in an `EClientSocket` pointer as the `this` parameter; furthermore, ctypes doesn't know anything about the `__thiscall` calling convention, so even if you did pass in an `EClientSocket` instance, it would be on the stack instead of in the ECX register.

The only real solution to this would be to export a C wrapper from your DLL that forwards the call to `eConnect`.  For example:

```
extern "C" DLLEXPORT
bool EClientSocket_eConnect(EClientSocket *This, const char *host, UINT port, int clientId)
{
    return This->eConnect(host, port, clientId);
}
```

However, even in that case, you have to be extra-careful on the Python side to construct an appropriate `EClientSocket` instance.  I'd strongly recommend reconsidering your approach here.

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking into [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/). It makes it easier to call on DLL files.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [Boost::Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/index.html#python.quickstart)